# Looping thru json to tabularize data in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, json-normalize

I have a nested json of lists and dicts with a total length of the list being n. When I use the below code, I get the first element in a tabular form with column headers.

```py
full_res = [
    [
        {
            "Col1": "c1v1",
            "Col2": "C2v1",
            "Col3": [{"m": "vm1", "n": "vn1", "p": "vp1"}],
            "col4": [],
        },
        {
            "Col1": "c1v2",
            "Col2": "C2v2",
            "Col3": [{"m": "vm2", "n": "vn2", "p": "vp2"}],
            "col4": [],
        },
    ]
]

df = pd.json_normalize(full_res[0][0])
```

Result is

```
      ** Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4   **

  0     C1V1   C2V1   [...] []
```

I would like to loop thru x and get a result like this

```
       **Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4  **                                                                                                                

  0     C1V1   C2V1   [...]  []  

  1     C1V2   C2V2   [...]  [] 
  .
  .
  n     C1Vn   C2Vn   [..]  []
```

I am trying to loop as below and its's not working

```py
while x <= n:
    df = pd.json_normalize(full_res[0][x])
    x = x+1
```

How can I loop and get all the values in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) takes care of the loop for you when called on the entire list of dicts `full_res[0]`, instead of just one `full_res[0][i]`.

```py
df = pd.json_normalize(full_res[0])
# Output
   Col1  Col2            Col3 col4
0  c1v1  C2v1  [{'m': 'vm1...   []
1  c1v2  C2v2  [{'m': 'vm2...   []
```